# Stack View constrained to margins leaves no margin

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, margins, stackview

I got some problem that I'm not sure how to solve...
I'm working on some lessons which are a little bit old (they are done in Swift 3), and I got a problem with constraints and margins. I'm just following the lesson and it says that for that stack view I need to put following constraints: 
[image: Given constraints]

After adding constraints to stack view I got this result:

[image: Result]

and this is the result I expected:

[image: Expected Result]

So my question is Why that stack view goes over margins, and how to fix it.
(reminder lesson was in Swift 3 and they got stack view inside the margins)

Comment: You're adding a constraint of 0 to the leading margin, what do you actually expect?

Comment: I'm expecting this result https://ibb.co/izWn6K

Comment: I think I know what you want. Please uncheck "Constrain to margins" and then add(select) new constraints.

Comment: Already tried but it's the same, im thinking about this margins https://ibb.co/jPLmGK

Comment: What's the difference between your expected result and above screen shot???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  That is confusing.  Selecting **Constrain to margins** used to leave a gap on the sides.  Now, when you select **Constrain to margins**, it constrains your view to the *Safe Area* but the view extends to the sides when the **constant** is `0`.

To fix it, change your leading and trailing constraints:

1. Open your leading constraint.  Click on `Safe Area.leading` and in the pop up select **Superview**.
2. Now click on `Superview.leading` and select **Relative to margin** and set **Constant** back to `0`.

Repeat this for the trailing constraint.

---

**Alternate solution**

Alternatively, you can leave your view constrained to the *Safe Area* and just set the constants to `16` (or `-16` depending on the order of the *items* in the constraint).

Comment: Weird! 1. Isn't this a bug? Or it's somehow by design? 2. It the same when you do through code? or it's only like this on storyboards?

Comment: @Honey, **Constrain to margins** should be changed to **Constrain to safe area** if they're going to change what it does, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks. didn't understand your answer to my 2nd question. If in code I constraint to margins with a constant of `0` would it be constrained to the margins or it would be constrained to the view's anchors itself  ie it would work like the storyboard?

Comment: @Honey, give me an example of how you would constrain to margins with a constant of 0 in code.

Comment: func pinToAllMargins(of view: UIView){
        
        let top = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor)
        let leading = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor)
        let trailing = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor)
        let bottom = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([top, leading, trailing, bottom])
    }

Comment: @Honey, that works in code.  I think the issue is merely how Interface Builder is interpreting *Constrain to margins*.  It really treats it as *Constrain to safe area* and the fix listed in the answer restores it to how it used to behave.